# What are the differences between "emigrate" and "immigrate"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

My teacher said,emigrate can be explained as move to another place, former place and later place are in the same country. immigrate can be explained as move to another country from other country. But what she said are different in  the Oxford Dictionary. Did she right？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the teacher is incorrect.

Immigration is moving to another non-native country. For instance, you live in India and apply for Permanent Residence to Canada, then you file for *immigration.* We have professional immigration consultants.

On the other hand, emigration is going out of a country.

See the fun - when you get your PR to Canada, you are both - immigrant and emigrant! You are immigrant *to* Canada and emigrant *from* India. Mind the preposition though.

There's one more - migration! It is not necessarily moving permanently. It could be a temporary stay. [See here.](https://www.dictionary.com/e/immigrants-vs-emigrants-vs-migrants/) Birds migrate.

Comment: In the example, people in India see you as an emigrant, people in Canada see you as an immigrant. People in Canada see you as an immigrant coming from India, immigrating in Canada. People in India see you has an emigrant moving to Canada.

Answer (score 2):

Immigrate is entering a country.  Emigrating is leaving it.

Comment: From the Latin _ex_ (out of) and _in_. The teacher was wrong.

Comment: Just read the whole post, teacher was dreadfully wrong.  Its internal, its just migration.

Comment: *It's internal, it's migration* - nope! Birds *migrate* to the whole new places, countries! *Migration* is largely temporary excursion due to climate change or food.

Comment: The conversation was about people, and anyone can see that “immigration” and “emigration” have “migration” as a root.  But when you are speaking of humans, migration is used for internal.  Otherwise you use the more accurate and precise terms available.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, _migration_ should be used for movement within a country. However, the term _economic migrants_ is used a lot these days with reference to people moving to another country.

Answer (score 2):

"Emigrate" is not used when discussing moving from one place to another within the same country. I would say that "move" is appropriate in that context.

"Emigrate"/"Immigrate" are used when talking about different countries. Let's say you are currently living in Australia but you are going to go and live in South Africa. You would then be emigrating from Australia and immigrating to South Africa.

A useful way to remember is: **E**migrate -> **E**xit and **I**mmigrate -> **I**nto

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Kate.  You are correct. Migration is any movement.  To use immigration or emigration you need a specified source of destination. All immigrants are also emigrants, and vice versa. Thus, when speaking generally about movements of people without a specified country you would use “migration”.  The question being asked, specifically, was whether the teacher was using to correct term for internal movements, which the teacher was not.   That correct term is “migration”.  I did not mean to imply or for anyone to infer that that was the sole correct usage of “migration”.

Comment: There are three terms in fact: migration, immigration and emigration.